# Google Chart with Proportional Y-Axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to get the y-axis of my stacked Google column chart proportional. I have tweaked the settings and am not able to get it to work. If the max column value is 1, there should only be 1 horizontal grid line. There should not be three with the value of 1. That doesn't make sense.

Here are my chart options:

```
var options = {
    colors: ['#ba1f1f', '#306b34', '#255f85', '#e28413', '#f24333'],
    bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
    chartArea: { left: 50, top: 10, width: '100%', height: '75%' },
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    animation: { startup: true, duration: 250, easing: 'linear' },
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
        slantedText: true
    },
    vAxis: {
        format: '#'
    },
    height: 350
};
```

And here is a picture of my problem:

[image: y-axis problem]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

**Update with @WhiteHat's suggestions:**

I tried your suggestion. It didn't really work. Here is my result if I set explicitly and not based on the column range max.

[image]

The total count for the 8 AM column is 7. 7 AM is 4 and 6 AM is 1.
I could have to do some other data manipulation to count the total number per column in the stacked column chart and find the max to not explicitly set the gridlines count. But that is after I can get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can add following option when *max column value is 1*

```
vAxis: {
    gridlines: {
        count: 2  //<-- default is 5
    }
},
```

or add decimals to `format : '#,##0.00'` to avoid repeating `1`

you can use data table method to check max column value

```
data.getColumnRange(columnIndex).max
```

Comment: Updated my question. Unfortunately it did not work @WhiteHat.